# Use MSBuild to upgrade and build a sln

Tags: visual-studio, command-line, msbuild

I'm trying to write a script to automatically download and build the external dependencies for a project I'm working on via the command line.

One of the projects I need only provides VS6, VS2005, and VS2008 solutions, however I need the project to be built with VS2010.

If I were to open any of those projects in VS2010 they would be upgraded and I could build that, however since I want this to be completely automatic, I was wondering if there was a way that the same upgrade could be done via MSBuild.

I tried just using the VS2010 Command Line to build the VS2008 sln file, but it still built it using the VS2008 compiler rather than using the VS2010 one.

Does anyone know if it's possible to do this using MSBuild?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like [devenv.exe /Upgrade](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w15a82ay.aspx) will do the silent upgrade for you. I just tested this with the sourcecode for [greenshot](http://getgreenshot.org/). Its really fast.

Answer (score 1):

An addition to *@Justin*'s answer:

If you intend to use it in batch scripts, you can use:

```
start /w devenv.exe YourSoulution.sln /upgrade
```

where `YourSoulution.sln` is the path or file name of your soultion file. `/w` is needed to prevent the next command to run before conversion is finished.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit of work, but [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/) is an open source IDE that used the Visual Studio sln and msbuild file formats. The latest version will offer to Upgrade a 2008 project to 2010 It shouldn't be terribly hard to write a Powershell script to do that via command line.